# Javascript Mocking functions that return Readable

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs

I have a simple function that calls my s3 service which will return a Promise

```
  downloadFile(fileName: string): Promise<Readable> {
    console.log(
      "Downloading an object with key - ",
      fileName
    );

    return this.s3service.getObject(fileName);
  }
```

I would like to mock the return of the object and assert it in the test like this:

```
it("should return readable if file present", async () => {
  const readable = new Readable();
  readable.push("test");

  jest
    .spyOn(s3service, "getObject")
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(readable));

  const file = await someService.downloadFile(
    TestConstants.reportName
  );

  expect(file).toBe(readable);
});
```

When i run the test, I face this error:

> Error [ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED]: The _read() method is not
> implemented
> at Readable.*read (internal/streams/readable.js:642:9)
> at Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:481:10)
> at maybeReadMore* (internal/streams/readable.js:629:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {   code:
> 'ERR_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED'

Would like some help on how I can properly mock a readable for example in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your production code just forward response from the service to outside, then just mock `getObject` to return anything, and expect the result should be `getObject` result and the service function will have called with correct parameter:

```
it("should return readable if file present", async () => {
  const readable = "readable-object" as unknown as Readable;
  jest.spyOn(s3service, "getObject").mockResolvedValue(readable);

  const actual = await someService.downloadFile(TestConstants.reportName);

  expect(actual).toBe(readable);
  expect(s3service.getObject).toHaveBeenCalledWith(TestConstants.reportName);
});
```